# How to install working GrowlVoice from scratch on Mac OS 10.9.5 (Mavericks)?

Tags: growl, google-voice, macos

As of [April 2014](https://twitter.com/GrowlVoice/status/455931023868448768), Google Voice apparently broke the [GrowlVoice](http://www.growlvoice.com) 2.0.3 interface. Since then various fixes/patches/etc have arisen. I need a procedure to reliably (re)install a working variant on Mac OS 10.9.5--I don't (yet) want to upgrade to Yosemite. I have to reinstall every time I'm forced to reboot my laptop, and on the last reboot, all my past tricks (that I can remember at least, derived from [these sources](http://www.one-tab.com/page/BnkXNnk6SOShTkFEtSx0dQ)) appear to be failing, with [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZhLS.png): "Sign in error: The operation couldn't be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 404.)"

I need a "from scratch," Mac OS 10.9.5 procedure to get Growl Voice working:

1. Remove all existing, conflicting files/artifacts.
2. Install http://www.growlvoice.com/trials/growlvoice-2.0.3.zip or some other canonical source of the App.
3. Fix/patch/whatever #2.
4. Preferably: make the above work through reboots.

Since I'm having trouble on this latest (re)install, I need a full, autonomous procedure (to de-install *all pertinent and potentially-conflicting files*, install GrowlVoice, install patches, etc); most if not all the procedures [here](http://www.one-tab.com/page/BnkXNnk6SOShTkFEtSx0dQ) appear to be partials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/d235j/GVFixer/issues/5), on approximately 2015-05-26, users first noticed that Google broke the API that supported [GrowlVoice](http://www.growlvoice.com/).